# Stata Outreg2: file handle __00000G not found

Tags: stata

I'm running a long list of regressions in Stata. Results are exported using `outreg2`. At random points in time, the execution stops at some `outreg2`  with the error `file handle __00000G not found`. When I rerun the whole exercise it works after some tries. Do you have any idea what could be the reason?
My code looks as follows where further regressions of the same type follow.

`xtreg l_GDP_capita i.year date_intens, fe r`

`outreg2 using year_DG_FE_gdp,  excel append  label addtext(DG FE, YES, YEAR FEs, YES) drop(i.year) ctitle(log GDP per capita, AP) replace`

`xtreg l_GDP_capita i.year date_intens if any_lez==1, fe r`

`outreg2 using year_DG_FE_gdp,  excel append  label addtext(DG FE, YES, YEAR FEs, YES) drop(i.year) ctitle(log GDP per capita, LEZ)`

Comment: On Statalist it is policy to explain where user-written files come from, and that is a good idea here too. `outreg2` is from SSC. Unfortunately you don't seem to have either a reproducible example for us or even a reproducible problem for yourself with your own data. I'd advise contacting the program author directly.

Comment: In the meantime,  you can try `estout`,  also from SSC.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

(1) your file name needs to be in quotations, so `outreg2 using "year_DG_FE_gdp", [blah]` instead of `outreg2 using year_DG_FE_gdp, [blah]`.

(2) In case you haven't done so, you need to set a directory.  `cd "whatever filepath you want to save to"` (or a global directory if you want to get fancy).  You may have done this earlier in your code (I usually do it at the top of a .do file), but since you've only posted the snippet here I can't tell.  Forgetting it is one of the classic problems people tend to have with outreg.

Comment: (1) That is not an error; the `" "` are only essential if there are embedded spaces in the filename, and the program would not even run with any such error. It is not clear what (2) has to do with the problem. Further note that `outreg2` (SSC) and `outreg` (SSC, SJ) are totally disjoint programs.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but I am having the same problem and I think this may arise when `outreg2` is writing to a directory that is being synced (e.g. Dropbox, Google Drive). I *believe* the conflict may come from a permissions conflict where Stata is trying to change the file as the sync software is uploading the change. If you can pause the syncing of the directory while running the Stata commands, this seemed to help me.